# Flask retrieve data

Tags: jquery, python, html, flask

I am populating a table and want to allow users to be able to delete data as they see fit. How can I retrieve the row values they want to delete server side? I am populating the table through a list as such:

```
  <tr>
    <td> {{ key }} </td>
    <td> {{ value[1] }}</td>
    <td> {{ value[0] }}</td>
    <td> {{ value[2] }}</td>
    <td> {{ value[3] }}</td>
    <td> {{ value[4] }}</td>
    <td> <button id="remove" value="Delete" name="btn2">Delete</button><td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a view that will take an `id` as an argument and then create a link in a template that will point to that view; or, even better, since you added a `jquery` tag to your question, create an AJAX request. I'd use a `DELETE` HTTP request for that since [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services) way is pretty much better, but you can get away with either GET or POST.

```
@app.route('/delete/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE'])
def delete_data(id=None):
    if id is None:
        return 'Please provide an object ID to delete!'

    object_to_delete = db.session.query(Data).filter_by(id=id)
    db.session.delete(object_to_delete)
    db.session.commit()
```

And then, in the template,

```
<a href="{{ url_for('delete', id=key) }}">Delete!</a>
```

Please note that I provided the easiest (but not really secure and/or proper) way. An AJAX request, while having a lot more code on the client-side :), would be really much better. There's a [Flask Mega-Tutorial article](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-ajax) that covers AJAX.